# How to find out which item of the list is click if the item's name are the same?

Tags: android

So basically I have records from a database, each record has its own unique ID (primary key) and its date(mm:hh mm/dd/yy) I would like to display those records on my app's listview. But having the time(mm:hh) is kind of ugly so i decided to only display the mm/dd/yy on the list, now the question is, when I program the onitemClick, how do I find out which item is being click?? Because I dont have the unique ID and the exact Date displayed on the list anymore.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for (int x = Records.size()-1; x >=0; x--)
        {
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("ID", String.valueOf(Records.get(x).getId()));
            map.put("date", Records.get(x).getDate()); //I am going to change this date to just mm/dd/yy


            aList.add(map);
        }

        sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.historyactivityrow,
                new String[]
                { "date" }, new int[]              
                { R.id.date });

        lv.setAdapter(sd);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3)
            {
                TextView tx = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                String s = tx.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, EditRecordActivity.class);          
                intent.putExtra("date", s); //I can't do this anymore because now the EditRecordActivity will not know the exact record to be edited.
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use arg2 (which is the position of the item that was clicked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to get the appropriate map from your arrayList?

For example:

```
long rowID = (aList.get(arg2)).get("ID");
```

I might be interpreting the setup wrong, but maybe this will lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in OnItemClickListener()

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3)
```

You are correct, you do not have a unique ID, but you could change that by using a `CursorAdapter` with a `LoaderManager`. When using a CursorLoader, the argument `long arg3` becomes the unique ID. It's a nice added benefit for using the `CursorLoader` with the `LoaderManager`, and probably `ContentProvider`, though I am telling you this so you can do some research. As for how you can do it, you have a few choices. As you put the items into the `ListView`, you could give it a tag with `setTag()` of the unique ID. That wouldn't be much extra code to implement with what you already have now. Your other option is to just check the `int arg2` which is the position in the `ListView`. The downside is you do not have the unique ID from the database. But it tells you which is what from the list which may be what you need. If you need the ID, well then the former would be what you do.

Hope it helps.